# html form not uploading file via post to a php script

Tags: php, html

So I have the following html form

```html
<form name="input" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="validate-signup.php" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
                name: <input type='text' name='name'/><br/>
                password: <input type='text' name='password'/><br/>
                email: <input type='text' name='email'/><br/>
                phone number: <input type='text' name='phone'/><br/>
                profile picture: <input type="file" name="file" size="25"/><br/>
                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/><br/>
            </form>
```

after which I have the following php code

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ($_FILES['file']['name'] != "") {
        copy($_FILES['file']['name'], getcwd()) or
                die("Could not copy file!");
    } else {
        die("No file specified!");
    }
}
```

the problem is $_FILES is empty. I've looked at past answers for this topic checked my php.ini, checked read write permissions etc but I'm still stumped. I'm running this using wamp, and editing my work in netbeans if this makes a difference.

Comment: Try adding an hidden input `max_size`. Further reading at the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Try to change the some configuratinon in php.ini upload_max_filesize = 10M post_max_size = 10M

Comment: You should be copying `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`

Comment: Usually you should use `move_uploaded_file`, not `copy`.

Comment: Please read this information on how to upload files using PHP: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: @odedta I believe it's better to read the official manual rather than w3schools, just my opinion.

Comment: I rather learn the basics from W3Schools, it is far better to understand than all the gibberish on php.net

Comment: @OfirBaruch I don't believe it is an issue with file size. I am testing uploads with 1KB txt files.

Comment: @Barmar That line does not get executed however, (isset($_POST['submit'])) evaluates to false.

Comment: Is that code in `validate-signup.php`?

Comment: @odedta according to that, unless I am mistaken, my file should upload. My form is almost identical (albeit the external javascript function). And as far as I know the $_FILES variable should store the files inside the temporary folder (wamp/tmp) that were uploaded. Was there a specific error you noted that made it seem like I do not know the basics?

Comment: If `isset($_POST['submit'])` return false it's has nothing to do with your file - the form itself isn't working. If you remove the file input field, it still won't work, right? Something here is really weird. Do you have anymore code in the `validate-signup.php` file, prior to that part of code?

Comment: If you put `var_dump($_POST)` before the `if`, do you see anything in there?

Comment: @OfirBaruch do have other code. But it executes after that statement.

Comment: @Barmar after doing that I get array (size=5)
  'name' => string 'asdas' (length=5)
  'password' => string 'affsafasf' (length=9)
  'email' => string 'afsafaf@afsafa.com' (length=18)
  'phone' => string '0716828067' (length=10)
  'submit' => string 'Submit' (length=6)

Comment: That clearly shows that `$_POST['submit']` is set. Check your code for typos.

Comment: @Barmar will do I'm sure its something silly like that

Comment: So it seem that my line <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"> was the issue, I hadn't got to styling so I hadn't created that file yet. After creating it it works fine.